# Universal Quantifier in Intuitionistic Logic

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

I have a very basic question about $\forall$ in intuitionistic first-order logic (IQL). It is well-known that in intuitionistic propositional logic (IPL), (\ref{dnlem}) and (\ref{dndne}) are both valid. 
\begin{equation}
\neg\neg(A\vee\neg A)\tag{LEM$_{\neg\neg}$}\label{dnlem}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\neg\neg(\neg\neg A\rightarrow A)\tag{DNE$_{\neg\neg}$}\label{dndne}
\end{equation}
My question is, are (\ref{dnlem}) and (\ref{dndne}) also valid for $\forall$? That is, shall we prove the following propositions?
$$\neg\neg(\forall xA(x)\vee\neg\forall xA(x)),\quad\quad\quad\neg\neg(\neg\neg\forall xA(x)\rightarrow\forall xA(x))$$
Thanks!

Comment: Note that while $\neg \neg(\forall x A(x) \lor \neg \forall x A(x))$ is intuitionistically valid, $\neg \neg \forall x (A(x) \lor \neg A(x))$ is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To take the first case, the same intuitionistic proof of e.g. $\neg\neg(\phi \lor \neg\phi)$ goes through whether $\phi$ is a propositional wff or involves quantifiers.

In the obvious way, just using uncontentious rules for the connectives, we show that the supposition $\neg(\phi \lor \neg\phi)$ entails a contradiction, and hence can infer its negation $\neg\neg(\phi \lor \neg\phi)$. Nothing here depends on what is 'inside' the wff we substitute for $\phi$.

So in particular, we can derive $\neg\neg(\forall xA(x)\vee\neg\forall xA(x))$ just using the rules for $\neg$ and $\lor$.

Similarly, just the inituitionistically acceptable connective rules suffice to show $\neg\neg(\neg\neg\phi \to \phi)$, whether or not $\phi$ contains quantifiers.